How to create "formula rows" while querying a table in Bigquery?
Is there a way to have multiple rows in a query result for one unique line in the table, from a calculation (it is not unnesting an array).
For example, in my bigQuery table I've got a price including taxes for a product and I want in my query result two rows for the same product with, in the first, the taxes amount and, in the second, its price exclusive of taxes.
My table:



Product
Price




Color TV
6000



Assuming a 20% taxes rate, what I want in my query results would be something like:



Product
Price




Color TV
5000


Taxes
1000



It would be the quivalent of following query:
WITH products_incl_taxes as  (SELECT "color TV" AS product, 6000 AS price)
select 
  product,
  price/1.2 as price_excl_taxes,
  price*(0.2/1.2) as taxes
from products_incl_taxes

Which gives following result:



Product
price_excl_taxes
taxes




Color TV
5000
1000



But with taxes and price excluding taxes as rows instead of columns (as in the table above the example query).
Is there a way to do so ?

I found a way to proceed in case some would be interested :)
WITH products_incl_taxes as  (SELECT "color TV" AS product, 6000 AS price),
 prepare_query as (
  select 
    concat (product,',taxes') as get_tax_details,
    price
  from products_incl_taxes)
select 
  product,
  case when product = 'taxes' then price*(0.2/1.2)
  else price/1.2 end as price

from prepare_query,unnest(SPLIT(get_tax_details, ',')) as product;

